# Reindex issues with Price, URL and Search

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, reindex, mysql-indexes

I've been trying to update my magento index and a few are few but I get the following error for 3 of them

```
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size' in /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

#1 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1910): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mirasvit/SearchIndex/Model/Resource/Catalogsearch/Fulltext/Engine.php(85): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('catalogsearch_f...', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mirasvit/SearchIndex/Model/Resource/Catalogsearch/Fulltext.php(128): Mirasvit_SearchIndex_Model_Resource_Catalogsearch_Fulltext_Engine->saveEntityIndexes(1, Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(210): Mirasvit_SearchIndex_Model_Resource_Catalogsearch_Fulltext->_saveProductIndexes(1, Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php(116): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_rebuildStoreIndex(1, NULL)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(84): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->rebuildIndex(NULL, NULL)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(446): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mirasvit/SearchIndex/Model/Index/Mage/Catalog/Product/Indexer.php(56): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mirasvit/SearchIndex/Model/Catalogsearch/Indexer/Fulltext.php(51): Mirasvit_SearchIndex_Model_Index_Mage_Catalog_Product_Indexer->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mirasvit_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#18 {main}
```

Any help or guidance would be great

If I disable the search I get the following

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size' in /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(287): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexAll()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
```

update: Error added to the top

Comment: what error you receive?

Comment: The above is the error I'm getting. I'm doing it via SSH. If I try via the web browser it just times out

Comment: It's just stack trace, mysql must return error. Please add full ssh output with command.

Comment: I tired via the browser but only a 500 error with nothing in the error logs and the SSH just keeps going until it times out. This is just with the price reindex

Comment: I have gotten the error now `Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size' in /var/www/vhosts/packaging-etc.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the Mirasvit/SearchIndex and look if it's running ok at that moment.

Comment: your answer seems to correct, as in stack trace we can see that mirasvit extensiona have added its own indexer, this might be the cause of issue..

Comment: Hi. Followed what you said and not getting the following
which I'll add to the end of my question

Comment: Is this an option? http://major.io/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/

Comment: I just found that about 3 hours ago funny enough and the test reindex was just done without any issue.